# Images атрибуты продукта Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

Нужна подсказка, по теме атрибутов продукта!

Точнее, я не могу понять как сделать `setup script` чтоб  `Product Information` в таб `Images` добавлялась еще колонка `checkbox-сов` (типа стандартной колонки `Exclude` или `Remove`).

**Сделал так:**

```
$imageAttributeCode = 'own_gallery_attribute';
$dataImageAttribute = array (
    'group'             => 'Images',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'frontend'          => 'catalog/product_attribute_frontend_image',
    'label'             => 'Own Gallery',
    'input'             => 'media_image',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => ''
);

$install->addAttribute('catalog_product', $imageAttributeCode, $dataImageAttribute);
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавило, все нормально, но вот только добавило `radiobutton`!  И то понятно потому что `'input' => 'media_image'` Но если сделать так `'input' => 'checkbox'` - добавляется один `checkbox` в низу страницы!

Нужна посказка:

**В чем я ошибаюсь ? Что упустил или делю не так ?**

Comment: Я думаю, вот этот grid не стандартно реализова, вам придёться переопределить этот template

Comment: @Naumov,  ого даже так .... ( А сильно это проблемно ?

Comment: Нет. Просто найди где в шаблоне иф медиа имайж.   И по аналогии сделай

Comment: @Naumov, вы имеете ввиду, найти шаблон для этого грида, скопировать + вставит новую колонку и уже сделаный ним переопределить стандартный ?

Comment: Нет какую ошибку, просто берёте тот template который описывает этот грид он не стандартный смотрите шаблон рендера checkbox image_view и делаете такой же для своего атрибута

Comment: @Naumov, я извиняюсь но туплю! Не могу понять о чём вы... Если не трудно можно ссылку какаю нибудь по этой теме..?

Comment: @Naumov, типа этого ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38434/adminhtml-how-to-add-custom-template-for-custom-product-attribute 

Я правильно Вас понял ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто переопределить этот шаблон

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml`

В нём добавить по анологии c этим

```
   <tr id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_template" class="template no-display">
                <td class="cell-image"><div class="place-holder" onmouseover="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.loadImage('__file__')"><span><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Roll Over for preview') ?></span><$
                <td class="cell-label"><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage$
                <td class="cell-position"><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text validate-number" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectNam$
                <?php foreach ($_block->getImageTypes() as $typeId=>$type): ?>
                <td class="cell-<?php echo $typeId ?> a-center"><input <?php if($_block->getElement()->getAttributeReadonly($typeId)) :?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif;?> type="radio" name="<?php echo $type['field'] ?>" o$
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td class="cell-disable a-center"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__$
                <td class="cell-remove a-center last"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage$
        </tr>
```

свою колонку типа рендера для аттрибута

Comment: так и сделал уже...Но когда мене нужно достать `$_block->getImageTypes()` -  почему то выдает ошибку     **Fatal error: Call to a member function getMediaAttributes() on null in  core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php on line 164**!  Я зделал `rewrite`  класса `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content` вроде все правильно, но не работает!

Comment: @Maybe_V приведи код как переопредил?

Comment: или привести код всех шагов ?

Comment: вот реврайт так сделал - http://pastebin.com/smNw4kWN

Comment: Да я имел виду php код реврайта и что именнно не работает? какая ошибка? @Maybe_V

Comment: вот так сделал http://pastebin.com/rcJrzVP6 не знаю что дальше ! Ошибка появилась (я там ниже привел её)

Comment: добавил колонку )) спасибо за подсказку !!